# GoogleMap v2 error on IE8 Chinese locale

Tags: google-maps, internationalization, cjk

Here is a simple code which doesn't work on IE8 on a https server with Chinese locale:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example</title>
   <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=${googleMapKey}"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    map.setUIToDefault();
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the above.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Bad copy and paste above.  http://jsfiddle.net/u3rjC/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
key=${googleMapKey}
```

Shouldn't there be an actual API key at this point?